How to organize the code so it will allow me to replace the original parts of the app with custom ones when needed?
I have a remote repo with the code commonly used in projects. These are components, directives, pipes, services, and interfaces - everything you would use in a project.  Right now they're registered in modules, but in the future, we plan to turn them into standalone components.
My problem is customization. Sometimes I want to change - for instance - the scrollbar which is used across the application. I'm expecting that my new custom-made element will replace the original scrollbar even inside the remote blocks of code.
It's like you've installed a huge package like an Angular Material, but you're unhappy with what the tooltip looks like and how it works. You want to replace it while keeping everything else from the original.
How should I organize my project?
